# Hostapd-mana doesnt show SSID'S

Tags: wifi, hostapd

I'm using the patched version of hostapd from the mana-toolkit (https://github.com/sensepost/hostapd-mana) to generate Access Points for Probe Requests.

But if I get my smartphone to connect with hostapd I get the following messages:

> wlan0: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx IEEE 802.11: authenticated
>
> wlan0: STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
>
> wlan0: AP-STA-CONNECTED xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
>
> KARMA: Successful association of xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx to ESSID '(null)'

So the association and connection works. But the ESSID should be "test123". I want it to display there to gather informations and use them elsewhere.

Is there any known fix to this? I haven't found anything yet and even tried different versions of hostapd resulting in the same problem.

Comment: I already tried to use the ssid_probe instead of ssid_probe_karma in the 802_11.c, which will be (null) as well. If I use the ssid attribute insted of ssid_probe_karma, I'll get my set ESSID (which in my case would be internet). So my guess would be that the ssid_probe_karma is not getting set the right way. But I haven't been able yet to find why and where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's fixed in the new version according to singe himself:

https://github.com/sensepost/mana/issues/27